# Cakephp SaveAssociated and Save - Using same Model Validation code

Tags: cakephp, indexing, save

Question: **How can I use the same code in the model validation (in particular for child models) for both SaveAssociated and Save function calls in CakePHP,... given that SaveAssociated implementations expect the form data array to contain a numeric index [0] for data fields belonging to a child model?**

Scenario:

Assuming I have a parent model with a hasMany relationship to several child models.

Typically if you use SaveAssociated to save data to all models at once, you would need to specify an index number (typically 0) on the view form input. Example:

```
echo $this->Form->input('MerchantControl.0.startdate', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'datepicker_start'));
```

As a result, any custom child model validation code will need to be written with [0] as well. See function urlParamNotUsedByOtherMerchants in the code sample below.

```
public $validate = array(
    'urlparam' => array(
        'In Use by other Merchants' => array(
            'rule' => 'urlParamNotUsedByOtherMerchants',
            'message' => 'URLPARAM belongs to another Merchant'
        )
    )
);


public function urlParamNotUsedByOtherMerchants($data) {
    $searchfilter = array(
                        //Because of SaveAssociated, need to refer to index [0] 
                        'MerchantControl.id !=' => $this->data['MerchantControl'][0]['merchant_id'],
                        'MerchantControl.urlparam ' => $data,
                        );        
    $merchantcontrol = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $searchfilter));
    if (sizeof($merchantcontrol) > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is there are many other instances where I will also be using a "Save" and not a "SaveAssociated" in maintainence views where i directly update or create the child model only. In this case, this model validation code is going to fail with an error saying index "[0]" not defined or something similar.

How can I use the same code in the model validation (in particular for child models) for both SaveAssociated and Save function calls in CakePHP?

Comment: Why would `MerchantControl.id` ever be equal to `MerchantControl.merchant_id` if not by chance? Shouldn't you compare against the foreign key column? Also what [**`validate` setting**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) are you using, `true` or `first`? And is the `merchant_id` value obtained from an insert, or is the value passed from the view? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to check whether the urlparam is already used by another merchant or in other words whether it is unique.

Why don't you use the built-in validation rule `isUnique`?

Example:

```
public $validate = array(
    'urlparam' => array(
        'In Use by other Merchants' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'URLPARAM belongs to another Merchant'
         )
    )
);
```

Comment: I can't use isUnique. A single merchant can use the same URLPARAM multiple times, and this may exist as multiple records in the child model.Hence I believe isUnique will not work in my case. My main question still stands though about using the same model validation code for SaveAssociated and Save